# Merging columns from identical tables in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I'm having difficulty finding a solution to this problem, as searching for merging SQL columns or adding columns from table gives a wide variety of results I don't want. It's much easier for me to illustrate with an example.

I have two tables:

**Table 1**

```
ColA  ColB  ColC
0     A     AL
1     B     DZ
```

**Table 2**

```
ColA  ColB  ColC
2     C     IS
3     D     KA
```

I want to merge these tables so the similar columns are basically combined, so I've got a new table with the same structure, and all of the values. So the output would be:

**Output**

```
ColA  ColB  ColC
0     A     AL
1     B     DZ
2     C     IS
3     D     KA
```

The issue is I want to find the distinct values across these columns from two similarly structured tables, so I cannot see how I can use a join for this, as if I join on any one value the other values will be lost, and a multiple-field join doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep duplicate rows you could use `UNION ALL` and if you want to remove duplicate rows from result set you could use `UNION` in following:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table2
```

*Note that `UNION ALL` working faster than `UNION`*

Answer (score 1):

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC from table1
union 
select ColA, ColB, ColC from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `union` operator allows you to place the result of one query after the other, and eliminates duplicates:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT cola, colb, colc
FROM   table2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC from table1
union 
select ColA, ColB, ColC from table2
```

You can also use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)